# Android destroying empty activity

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity

We have a activity A which get invoked via intent from other application.
This activity A starts activity B and opens webview inside activity B.

*As activity A is empty activity it gets destroyed by android, in some of the cases.*

**Ask:**

1. What are the possible reasons due to which this activity is getting killed aggressively?
2. How can we prevent this destruction of activity by android and retain it till the processing is done? as activity A will be require to setResult while redirection back to source app.

Below is the stack trace for ref:

```
09-01 14:15:03.666 27776 27776 D ActivityA: Printing stack trace:
09-01 14:15:03.666 27776 27776 D ActivityA:     at dalvik.system.VMStack.getThreadStackTrace(VMStack.java:-2)
09-01 14:15:03.666 27776 27776 D ActivityA:     at java.lang.Thread.getStackTrace(Thread.java:1841)
09-01 14:15:03.666 27776 27776 D ActivityA:     at com.app.ActivityA.printStackTrace(SourceFile:293)
09-01 14:15:03.666 27776 27776 D ActivityA:     at com.app.ActivityA.onDestroy(SourceFile:280)
09-01 14:15:03.666 27776 27776 D ActivityA:     at android.app.Activity.performDestroy(Activity.java:8406)
09-01 14:15:03.666 27776 27776 D ActivityA:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnDestroy(Instrumentation.java:1378)
09-01 14:15:03.666 27776 27776 D ActivityA:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:5640)
09-01 14:15:03.666 27776 27776 D ActivityA:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:5686)
09-01 14:15:03.666 27776 27776 D ActivityA:     at android.app.servertransaction.DestroyActivityItem.execute(DestroyActivityItem.java:47)
09-01 14:15:03.666 27776 27776 D ActivityA:     at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityTransactionItem.execute(ActivityTransactionItem.java:45)
09-01 14:15:03.666 27776 27776 D ActivityA:     at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState(TransactionExecutor.java:176)
09-01 14:15:03.666 27776 27776 D ActivityA:     at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:97)
09-01 14:15:03.666 27776 27776 D ActivityA:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2374)
09-01 14:15:03.666 27776 27776 D ActivityA:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
09-01 14:15:03.666 27776 27776 D ActivityA:     at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:233)
09-01 14:15:03.666 27776 27776 D ActivityA:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:344)
09-01 14:15:03.666 27776 27776 D ActivityA:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8248)
09-01 14:15:03.666 27776 27776 D ActivityA:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:-2)
09-01 14:15:03.666 27776 27776 D ActivityA:     at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:589)
09-01 14:15:03.666 27776 27776 D ActivityA:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1071)
```

Comment: `As activity A is empty activity it gets destroyed by android, in some of the cases.` Has nothing to do with an activity beeing empty or not. Has everything to do with an OS that can kill an activity at any moment when the activity is not the top activity. (Lesson one).

Comment: Turn activity A into a FORGROUND SERVICE, that would not get killed easily.

Comment: Don't worry about it.  A may be killed, but when you go back to it it will be recreated.  Even if launched for result, the link to the calling activity will be passed on to the new version that gets recreated.  This is all expected Android behavior.

Comment: If you just want to have some data saved in your empty activity when you go back to it, then I think add a ViewModel to it. Cause whenever android OS needs resources it can even destroy paused activity let alone a stopped one.

Comment: @JamesNickel - We are not having requirement of foreground service. Is there any other way to retain activityA?

Comment: @GabeSechan - We don't go back to activityA. Rather after processing we have a cordovaPlugin which kills activityB and expects to have activityA to fallback and to set result while redirecting back to source app.  Is there any other way to retain activityA?

Comment: @AvadhutPatade I don't think your description of what you're trying to do makes any sense at all then.  There is no such thing as "have an activity to fallback to".  There's the back stack, which you can navigate backwards through, but there's no other way to go back to an Activity.  And there's no way to make sure an Activity is retained in memory, only the current foreground Activity has that promise.  I think you should start by clearly articulating the entire flow you want here, as I think you have a lot of confusion about how Android works.